# Login loop Fedora 19 GNOME 3

Tags: fedora, gnome, login, gnome3

I've just installed Fedora 19 in my hard drive which has some 100GB+ free space.

I'm not able to login to Fedora now. After entering the correct credentials, I got to see the console-like black screen with some text e.g. `[OK] something ...` then back to the login screen again. It is endless.

Note that I have definitely entered the correct password because when I didn't it showed me "authentication failed"

History:
Everything went smoothly after installation. I installed Chrome and git. I set up Eclipse executable. I edited `/etc/environment` so as to able to run `abd` executable (I'm doing Android development)

I ran:

```
yum update
```

I also ran (according to this):

```
yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686
```

My Fedora is 64 bit.

I have already reinstalled Fedora after this issue happened for the first time.

I also did the following:
Press "E" when grub shows the kernel options (I'm dual-booting Fedora and Windows 7) Added "3" to the end of the linux ... line Press "F10"
but nothing, even `ls`, works in such command line mode so no luck for me at all

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the problem and a workaround.

The cause of the problem is that I edited `/etc/environment`

At first, I foolishly put:
`PATH="$PATH:...`
which definitely doesn't work because we can't have variable in the plain-text file (it's not a script).

After that, I changed it to:
`PATH=/home/ericnguyen/adt/sdk/platform-tools`
still doesn't work
I may have made a typo - wrong path
For the experiment's sake, the directory `/home/ericnguyen/adt/sdk/platform-tools` is not even there yet - I skipped creating it to save time

Workaround:
My goal was to simply have the above directory included in PATH environment variables for all users for good.
Despite the popular answer from many sources on the Internet mentioning `/etc/environment` (which I have successfully used many times on my Centos servers and my Mac), `/etc/profile`, `bash` stuffs, I have learnt that best practice is to put a shell script inside `/etc/profile.d/`
e.g. `env_path.sh`
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/ericnguyen/adt/sdk/platform-tools

Benefits of this approach:

- Does what I need - apply PATH to all users forever
- It's a script so there's a lot of things I can do
- It's a script so it's easier to
  troubleshoot and is not as dangerous as modifying `/etc/environment`